# What is the meaning of "bring it before the mind"?

Tags: phrases

What is the meaning of the following statement?
Does the part "bring it before the mind" is a common phrase?

> In the following pages it has been his aim to give an interesting,
> and, at the same time, a truthful picture of jungle life—such a
> picture as may **bring it before the mind** of the European reader without
> exaggeration or false glitter.
>
> — *Forest Life in Ceylon,* W. Knighton, 1854

Comment: 'bring it before the mind of the European reader without exaggeration or false glitter.' = 'present the European reader with a true picture of [jungle life], one without distortion for effect, or glamorisation'. Obviously, repeating the 'picture' metaphor would be poor style. Though I'd say 'bring it before the mind' is redundant here. // "... an interesting, and, at the same time, truthful picture of jungle life – without exaggeration or false glitter – for the European reader.""

Comment: The more usual expressions are "flashed before his mind" / "flashed before his mind's eye", and "brought it to mind" / "brought it into my mind" etc. "Brought it before my / his / the ... mind" show few results on a Google search, and I'd say are rarely used.

Comment: Hence, the OP's actual question is: **"Does the part "bring it before the mind" is a common phrase?"**.  The answer is nothing more than two letters: **"No."**  But most typically a mammoth discussion ensues.

Comment: *Some comments removed.* A mammoth discussion ensues only if it is started. Please use comments for requesting clarification on the question, not for discussing its own merits.